# Regular Expression Extractor Parameterization

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm just getting started with JMeter and have run into a problem. I'm using the *Regular Expression Extractor* to scrape and parameterize a string that I named *CouponID*, as follows:

"coupon_id":”(.+?)”  (from the following json response "coupon_id":"320747")

[image]

But when I plug the variable (${CouponID}) in the value field of a parameter in the subsequent http request, its request URL ends up looking like this and the test fails:

```
http://[...]/coupon.json?id=${CouponID}  (instead of [...]/coupon.json?id=320747)
```

When I include a valid default value, the URL is constructed correctly and the test passes.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead.

```
(?<=\"coupon_id":")(.*?)(?=\")
```

Preview: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzBUg.jpg

Comment: Thanks very much Felipe!  I finally got "coupon_id":”(.+?)” to work after restarting the application--something must have hung in a strange state.